# "Executable script code found in signature block" on second ARM deployment in VS 2015

Tags: powershell, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

```
[ERROR] At line:1 char:2297
+ $UI = 'VS-'; if (!(Test-Path 'C:\Users\LavaHot\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Pow ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
```

I get this error on my second deployment, no matter if the previous deployment was successful or not. If I restart Visual Studio, it works again, but only one time. I'm running Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and everything is fully updated.

I just created this Azure Resource Group project and I am having just a ton of problems with getting my deployments working. This is one of them.

**EDIT**: To clarify, in Visual Studio 2015, I added an Azure Resource group project with a website and SQL template. This error always occurs after the first deployment attempt, even with a fresh template.

Comment: Can you make this code not one massive line so that we can see the code near character _2297_!

Comment: This is the error output, I did not write the underlying code in the script. I didn't truncate the error either.

Comment: I think you've found a bug.  One workaround would be to just call the PowerShell script directly instead of through VS.  I'd like to understand the potential bug though.  Can you email me some detail?  bmoore at microsoft.com...

Comment: I'd be happy to first thing Monday. Thanks, bmoore!

Comment: yeah. ive got the same issue. anyone found a fix?

Comment: I'm having this same exact problem on one of the development machines. The deployment works the first time but always fail with the same error the second time. Did you find a solution or fix for this? My workaround is to close Visual Studio and open again

Comment: I had the same thing in PowerShell ISE.  Closing the reopening the ISE fixed it.

Comment: this is such an annoying issue. really wish there was a fix (not a workaround)